# Never ending saga of audio problems (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS)

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

Release: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Sound Card : Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio

Context: Fairly new to linux (maybe my second month). I like to think I'm not an absolute noob but I'm still a beginner. Also completely new to askubuntu so I apologise if my formatting is incorrect.

1. Upon installing Ubuntu, no sound. I tried pretty much every solution on the first page of google to no avail. I suspect that I may have inadvertently caused myself more problems by doing this, especially by messing with the default files. I tried all the sound troubleshooting advice, nothing. Configuring alsamixer, pavucontrol... nothing.
2. Eventually I solved it. The problem was audio wasn't assigned to my user account. I assigned it, restarted the computer, turned up the audio and tried watching a youtube video and... *PSHHHHHH*... The loudest white noise I have ever heard coming from a computer put me into a state of shock, almost certainly rendering me permanent ear damage. I suspected this was because all the sound knobs under alsamixer ("PCM" in particular) were turned all the way up, so I changed them. However, changing volume through alsamixer wouldn't work, and every time I tried to change audio through the sound settings or with the volume control keys on my keyboard it would just reset to max values. I looked up how to fix this and found a solution. NOTE: only headphones were working, my speakers still weren't producing sound.
3. The problem was... The solution (which involved messing with the default files again) gave me the same problem I started with, only dummy output and no audio... *GRHHHH*... Again, I've circled forum after forum looking to fix it. I've reinstalled pulseaudio, followed the sound troubleshooting etc etc. When I run lspci it can identify my sound card but pacmd won't list it.

Becoming very frustrated. Maybe there is something obvious I am missing. Maybe I need to provide more information. Unsure of why this has been so difficult. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Without knowing what all solutions you tried, we really cannot do anything. Does Ubuntu show the sound icon?